# COM object lifetime

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

Consider the following scenario:

This code executed by thread A:

```
CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
globalSomeSTAComObject.CreateInstance((__uuidof(CLSID_SomeSTAComObject));
return 0;
```

Now after thread A is done it's execution does the `default STA` "inherit" globalSomeSTAComObject and it can be used by other threads ?
Or does this object becomes unusable ?

Same question regarding thread A but now consider the object to be MTA Com object that was created on MTA thread.
When thread A is done it's execution does the MTA Com object is still alive within `Multithreaded Apartment` and can be used ?

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr xml;

unsigned __stdcall CreateXml(void*)
{
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    xml.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::FreeThreadedDOMDocument60));
    xml->load("c:\\test.xml");
    return 0;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    HANDLE handle = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, CreateXml, nullptr, 0, nullptr));
    WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
    long numOfSections = xml->documentElement->childNodes->length;  //This works why ?
    xml.Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Please not the in `CreateXml` I intentionally didn't call `CoUninitialize` because I want to know what is the state of xml object in this scenario.

Comment: The code snippet shown is dangerous. Not only you don't show how you are going to do `CoUnitinialize`, but you also make certain assumptions on using STA specific COM pointer both on other threads AND after hosting STA/thread completion. `globalSomeSTAComObject` can only be used on this thread and before `CoUnitinialize`. Use on other threads might work out, but is generally incorrect and behavior is undefined.

Comment: If MTA thread create MTA object (global object) and terminates. Is the object still `alive` in MTA apartment ? Or in this case the behavior is undefined ?

Comment: COM requires that you terminate your COM activity before calling `CoUninitialize`. Hence, leaving a COM pointer outside of this initialization is incorrect. In MTA case however it is a far less frequent problem since the pointer is still valid in presence of any else MTA thread. All in all, you sometimes can leave COM object "leaked" from helper MTA thread, but summing everything up I would say that you are still putting your question somehow incorrectly. There is something wrong in first place, in trying to have a COM singleton object outside of COM initialization.

Comment: But if the object belong to COM and created in MTA apartment why is it considered to be undefined behavior ? Assuming there are other MTA threads running when MTA thread that created that specific object terminates.

Comment: You have to make sure you release your COM pointer before last MTA thread calls its `CoUninitialize`. As simple as this. If you cannot ensure this, be ready to get an access violation issue once the app is terminating.

Comment: You can't create an STA object from an STA thread, terminate the thread and expect the object to work at all. By definition, the creating STA thread has to pump messages for the STA object to interact with other threads. If the thread ends, there is no message queue anymore, and there is nobody to pump it. If you are doing this and somehow the object is still responding to other threads, you are passing unmarshaled pointers between threads, and that's illegal in COM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the threading models of both the COM object itself and the thread that creates it.

If the object is apartment-threaded, it will live in its own STA. If an STA thread creates the object, the thread runs in the same STA as the object and receives a direct pointer to the object. If an MTA thread creates the object, a new STA is created and the thread receives a proxy to the object in the STA.  In either case, the object must be marshalled if other threads want to access it.

If the object is multi-threaded, it will live in the MTA. If an STA thread creates the object, the thread receives a proxy to the object in the MTA. If an MTA thread creates the object, it receives a direct pointer to the object.  The object can be directly accessed by other MTA threads, but must be marshalled if accessed by STA threads.

If the object is free-threaded, it will live in an STA if created by an STA thread, and will live in the MTA if created by an MTA thread. The above rules then apply.

This topic is discussed in detail on MSDN:

[Processes, Threads, and Apartments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693344.aspx)

[Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)

[COM+ Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686448.aspx)

Comment: Thank for your reply but it doesn't answer my question regarding object's lifetime. If STA thread create STA object and then terminates, can the object be accessed by other threads ? Same question but now MTA thread creates MTA object and then terminates does this object stays `alive` in MTA apartment and can be accessed ?

Comment: The object's lifetime is governed by its reference count, not the lifetime of the thread that created it. If you read the documentation I linked to, threads and apartments are separate things. Threads run in apartments, but they do not create or own them, COM does. So, when a thread creates the object, its reference count is 1. Before the thread terminates, it must decrement the object's reference count. When other threads access the object, they must increment and decrement the reference count as needed. When the reference count falls to 0, the object frees itself.

Comment: Well I've tested the scenarios I've talked about and it seems like in both of them after the creating thread terminated the objects where still `alive` and accessible by other threads that initialized COM. I was wondering if the is just a fluke or it is behavior by design ?

Comment: @JobNick You're probably not managing your reference counts correctly. Thread termination doesn't decrement the reference counts of COM objects. If the thread is still holding references to a COM object when it terminates then the object will be leaked. If a STA object is still accessible from other threads after the STA thread for that object exits then you've probably been passing unmarshalled COM pointers to the other threads, so they end up calling the object on their own thread like a MTA object. This the unsafe behaviour Roman R is talking about in his comment to your question.

Comment: I'm using COM object wrapped with COM smart pointers. As I mentioned the COM objects I was referring to are MSXML DOMDocument60 for STA thread and FreeThreadedDOMDocument60 for MTA thread. While the COM smart pointer is IXMLDOMDocumentPtr and it's global. So that why I was curios what happens to that object when the thread that created it terminates. On both cases I was able to use it from other COM thread (both MTA and STA).

Comment: COM smart pointers manage the reference count for you, but you still have to pay attention to the reference count. Your global variable is a smart pointer. It has an active reference to the object. So the object remains alive after the creating thread terminates. Simple as that.

Comment: Objects live in the apartment they are created in. If it is a STA then there is an apartment just for that thread. Ending that thread destroys the apartment. If you didn't destroy all the objects that existed in that apartment yet then you cause undefined behaviour (i.e. COM spec doesn't cover this and it's hard to say that this is a good idea!)

Answer (score 0):

A COM object lives for as long as it thinks there are references to it, i.e. the reference count is greater than zero.  All cross-apartment links to an apartment's objects are released when `CoUninitialize` is called.  Stubs are released, decrementing the actual objects' refcounts.  Stale proxies are notified and fail at anything other than refcounting, by returning an RPC error HRESULT.

However, I believe that exiting a thread without the necessary calls to `CoUninitialize` does not have specified behavior.  I can see the scenario where nothing happens, so you may end up with e.g. stale links to STA objects, which message loops will never run, because you pulled the rug (thread) underneath it, or dead MTA objects, which will error if there is not at least one MTA thread running.  Another scenario is if OLE32.dll detects this in its `DllMain` on `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` and does the necessary cleanup anyway, thus erroring a bit earlier on a subsequent proxied method invocation.

You must not store unmarshalled interface pointers, because if you do, invoking its methods from other apartments will most likely cause trouble, e.g. STA objects might not be ready for multithreading or might fail to access thread-local storage, and MTA objects might not be ready for Windows message loops or reentrancy.

Be aware that there may exist multiple STAs, and no STA object ever switches their apartment due to COM itself, only if by returning a direct, non-marshaled interface pointer.  So, when an STA dies, its objects are not "adopted" by an existing or future STA, not even the main one (the first STA) or the default one (one created out of necessity by COM itself), which may be the same.

Also, after an MTA is created, every new thread belongs to the MTA implicitly, if not explicitly initialized at the first use of COM.   However, such threads don't keep the MTA alive.

---

P.S: I've read from your comments that your MTA object is in fact a free-threaded object.  There's quite a difference, as the free-threaded object bypasses in-process marshaling, thus they'll belong to whatever apartment actually creates them, its methods run in whatever the current apartment is and they must be ready for both multithreading and reentrancy within modal Windows message loops due to cross-apartment, non-blocking calls from an STA.